# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing

Tags: java, html, parsing, thymeleaf

I am trying to form an email template using Thymeleaf. The email contains data in Tabular form. I am getting an error while parsing it. 
My HTML Template -

```
<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org'>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <style type='text/css'> td, th { border: 1px solid black; } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <p>Hi Team,</p>
            <p>Kindly find the details</p>
            <table class='table table-striped' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='1300' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Cus</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Loc</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Name</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Ins Name</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>IP</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Flavor</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>OS</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Env</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>DC</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Date</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Status</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align='center' th:each='value : ${values}'>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.cusName}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.loc}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <a th:href="@{${value.vmURL}}" th:text="${value.name}"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.instanceName}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.ip}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.flavor}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.os}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <a th:href="@{${value.envURL}}" th:text="${value.envName}"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <a th:href="@{${value.dcURL}}" th:text="${value.dcName}"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.date}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.status}'></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>With regards,</p>
            <p>Auto Notifier </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error -

```
 ERROR [http-nio-8082-exec-200] o.t.TemplateEngine.process(1136) | [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8082-exec-200] Exception processing template "<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org[...] </p></div></body></html>": An error happened during template parsing (template: "<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org[...] </p></div></body></html>")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org[...] </p></div></body></html>")
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.v2.service.impl.ReportImpl.emailNotificationForDailyVM(ReportImpl.java:1041) [classes/:1.0]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.v2.service.impl.ReportImpl.emailTemplateForDailyVM(ReportImpl.java:1027) [classes/:1.0]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.v2.service.impl.ReportImpl.generateEmailForVM(ReportImpl.java:1010) [classes/:1.0]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.v2.service.controller.ReportController.generateDailyVMEmail(ReportController.java:138) [classes/:1.0]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.v2.service.controller.ReportController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e586d978.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:97) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.util.RequestBodyFilterAspect.beforeControllerLogging(RequestBodyFilterAspect.java:89) [catalyst.product-1.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.v2.service.controller.ReportController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b77d252.generateDailyVMEmail(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.service.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:81) [catalyst.product-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:100) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at com.tcl.gvg.catalyst.service.filter.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:29) [catalyst.product-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.24]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "value.instanceName" (template: "<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org[...] </p></div></body></html>" - line 1, col 1740)
        at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "value.instanceName" (template: "<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org[...] </p></div></body></html>" - line 1, col 1740)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:165) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:126) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:293) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 118 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'instanceName' cannot be found on object of type 'org.json.simple.JSONObject' - maybe not public?
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:372) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 143 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'instanceName' cannot be found on object of type 'org.json.simple.JSONObject' - maybe not public?
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:372) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267) ~[spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 143 common frames omitted
```

It gives error while parsing `value.instanceName` and `value.ip`.
I have tried giving both of them in double quotes but same error occurs.
Please help me with with, where am I forming the template wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `JSONObject` the Java class doesn't have a property named `instanceName`. Generally speaking you shouldn't be using such low-level tools directly and should be allowing Spring to convert to a semantically meaningful Java class for you.

Comment: Hi @chrylis-onstrike- Can you please elaborate more on this? As I said all other properties are working fine. I have a JSONObject which contains all these properties.

Comment: Well, the specific error is: `Property or field 'instanceName' cannot be found on object of type 'org.json.simple.JSONObject' - maybe not public?` . If the other fields are working, then it suggest that the data is missing for just that field.